# C++ member functions as friends

Tags: c++, friend, member-functions

f is a member function of struct Y, and declared as a friend in struct X. Why can f not access private members of X as intended?

Please help me understand how to make member functions friends effectively. I have easily found accessible examples of global functions as friends, but not member functions.

```
struct X;

struct Y {
    void f(X* a);
};

struct X {
private:
    int i;
public:
    friend void Y::f(X* a);
};

void Y::f(X* x) {
    x->i = 0; // Error: member "X::i" (declared at line 9) is inaccessible
}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce http://ideone.com/goHLoC what compiler do you use?

Comment: Works for me g++ 5.1.0

Comment: If that's visual studio, intellisense does seem to report an error, but it should compile just fine.

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me. Create a public accessor for `X` or make Y a friend of `X`. Prefer public accessors to friends for loose coupling and scalable architecture.

Comment: Thank you all, I am using Visual Studio. @AlexG, thank you in particular. I didn't realise programs could compile in visual studio even when intellisense was reporting an error. Please feel free to submit your comment as an answer for credit.

Answer (score -1):

Wouldn't F need to be virtual? I could be wrong.

Comment: Not the dv, but no, making `Y::f(X*)` virtual would make no difference.